# Discard Button (or Link) don't appear

Tags: bug

When I'm in the process of making an answer, sometimes happens that the discard (red) link (or button) don't appear. So I don't have another alternative that refreshing the page for cancel my current answer. You can check next image I have captured from one of these situations:

[image]

Is this a known bug?

Comment: Thanks, from that answer, there is a link to this one: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/allow-questions-to-be-saved-as-drafts-prior-to-posting/66238#66238 that appears to have better information about this. Anyway, i'm sure I was sitting more than `45s` experimenting before I tried to cancel.